# decoding magnet uri from coppersurfer.tk scrape file

Tags: decode, bittorrent, torrent, magnet-uri

i try to decode the hash to build magnet uri from scrape file (downloaded from coppersurfer.tk site)

after splitting the huge file

i try to decode the hash file

```
hash = hashlib.sha1(f).hexdigest() # hash info
```

and gotten list such as

```
6768033e216468247bd031a0a2d9876d79818f8f : {'downloaded': 2374, 'complete': 0, 'incomplete': 75}
e5eaaedf19d4602337c71b041a669b9d70bda764 : {'downloaded': 0, 'complete': 0, 'incomplete': 1}
a2e43672a55dcda5d6b1cbdf356da4f6a3e6178d : {'downloaded': 0, 'complete': 0, 'incomplete': 1}
ea01e99635aa17b7d9803c3004210202b1e9e612 : {'downloaded': 1, 'complete': 0, 'incomplete': 2}
b9c569eb1820a1a67633757fc96801ed0c8f3281 : {'downloaded': 1085, 'complete': 1, 'incomplete': 0}
92c9de8c9a40405f56aa5c4d55c22720a208207f : {'downloaded': 0, 'complete': 0, 'incomplete': 1}
a398de47b654426f4ef39054c8bbfe9f0348cd74 : {'downloaded': 304, 'complete': 1, 'incomplete': 0}
11a9f43eead2164042c87bf75fa72d885d4afe86 : {'downloaded': 0, 'complete': 0, 'incomplete': 1}
254b675173ccb75085a0e25a1da6c1ec2c5846a0 : {'downloaded': 0, 'complete': 0, 'incomplete': 1}
```

but when i combined it to create magnet uri such as

```
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:6768033e216468247bd031a0a2d9876d79818f8f
```

and try to download it in torrent client, it doesnt seems to work ( i try multiple other hashes with same result)

do you know what i need to do in order to decode the hash correctly?

thank you for your help

Comment: how can i do this in PHP ?

Comment: can you share whole piece of code ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

The scrape file `full_scrape_not_a_tracker.tar.gz` contains a *bencoded* full scrape and it seems from the examples, that it has been decoded correctly.

The conversion to magnet link is also done correctly.
However, a search for `6768033e216468247bd031a0a2d9876d79818f8f` turns out that:

```
6768033e216468247bd031a0a2d9876d79818f8f = sha1( 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 )
```

i.e it's not a real *info_hash*, so it's likely that the full scrape contains some bogus *info_hashes*.

It's probably better to test torrents where there are seeders,
i.e those there the `'complete'` value is not zero.
So continue to test hashes and eventually one will turn out to be a real torrent.

---

Also, adding a tracker to the magnet link, will probably speed up the lookup a bit.

```
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:6768033e216468247bd031a0a2d9876d79818f8f&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969
```

Comment: hi, 

1. how did you a search for 6768033e216468247bd031a0a2d9876d79818f8f?  

2. how did you do  6768033e216468247bd031a0a2d9876d79818f8f = sha1( 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ).  

Thank you

Comment: 1. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=6768033e216468247bd031a0a2d9876d79818f8f&ia=web -> https://old.lwn.net/Articles/262328/ 2. I used **Bencode Editor** that I already had open, but there is many other tools that can be used.

Answer (score 0):

The scrape file should already contain the hashes for each torrent in their raw (20byte) representation, no additional hashing is required. All you need to do is to convert them to hex representation.